# Sidetiq Perform Params Missing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq, sidetiq

How do I pass sidetiq params. When I call perform it complains the params are missing. How does sidetiq set those two params?

```
def perform(last_occurrence, current_occurrence)
```

https://github.com/tobiassvn/sidetiq/wiki/Basic-Usage

Comment: Can you clarify your question, I'm not sure what you're asking?

Comment: Ok, found the problem. "Sidetiq will check the method arity before enqueuing the job" which means that Sidetiq internally checks if the `perform` method takes zero or two params and acts accordingly. If you want to run this method from rails console you should pass two float numbers to as params (I guess 0.0 should be ok but you have to check)

Comment: @MikeSzyndelYou saved my day, its so stupid of sidetiq to do so. I had a wrapper which would fail and i was baffled whats going on who is passing args? :+1